# How to return value of array with Alamofire Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

My goals is to return a value when Alamofire is ready with his tasks.
Below script is part of my singleton, that will be called by my viewController. I have looked around and there are examples of where a completion handler is implemented with Alamofire.

**Singleton:**

```
func getPeople() -> [Person] {
        
    var persons:[Person] = []
        
    Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                
            for field in json {
                // Reference to person class
                let person = Person()
                    
                // Properties will be fill in
                ...
                ...

                // Add properties to the person object
                persons.append(person)
                    
           }

        }
            
    }
    return persons
        
}
```

**Viewcontroller**

I will call above function in my `ViewController.swift` and add it to an array of People.

```
var persons = [Person]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let request = requestHandler()
    self.persons = request.getPeople()
}
```

Because Alamofire will be asynchroon, I don't get returned the array of persons. How do I return the value `persons` to a function that is called from my `viewcontroller.swift`? I am using Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **closures** for this purpose:

```
func getPeople(success: (([Person])->Void)?, failure: ((Error)->Void)?) {
    //create Alamofire request
    //if everything was fine call success block with people array passed into it
    //if failure occurred, call failure block with error.
    //In any case you must call either `success` of `failure` here
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ServerManager.sharedInstance.getPeople(
            success: { people in
                //use people here, update UI if needed
            },
            failure: { error in
                //show an error
        })
```

You can read more about closures in swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), but I will leave some explanation about your particular case:

Basically, `(([Person])->Void)?` is a type of the closure. It means that the closure will accepts an array of `Person` objects and is returning nothing (`Void`). `?` in the end means that it's an optional parameter, so you can pass `nil` when you call `getPeople` function if you're not interested in the callback at all.

The same about `((Error)->Void)?` failure closure. If you call it, you must pass an `Error` object to describe what actually went wrong.

**Why you closures should be optional?**

For example, you have an endpoint for sending user's location to the server. Sometimes you will want to run some code after request is finished and sometimes you don't care if it fails or not (you're just sending the coordinates in background). If you don't need a callback, you can pass an empty closure or nil. In fact there is nothing wrong in using empty closure like `{ _ in }` but it's a bit cleaner if you pass `nil`. You can meet optional closures in some UIKit methods as well:

[present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

[animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate)

P.S. You can also design your method in such way that it has **only one** `completion` callback with two optionals:

```
func getPeople(completionHandler: (([Person]?, Error?)->Void)?) {}
```

Personally I prefer two closures because it's more evident and readable, though it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Can you tell me what is happening with succes and failure parameters? I know that succes will be called if the request is successfully and failure when it failures, but the use of the `(([People])->Void)?` and `((Error)->Void)?` isn't clear to me right know..

Comment: @Caspert I've just updated the answer with more details about closures.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The only thing what I doesn't understand is, way should you pass nil in the closure? Do you have an example for that. Because Void will return you by default nothing if I understand it?

Comment: @Caspert: Check the update, I've added a some details about optional closures.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. It's a lot clearer for me know! I will try it out. Thanks!